# Error happens when I run "npm install"

Tags: git, npm, npm-install, hexo

I am planning to use `hexo` to create my GitHub blog, When I run `hexo init`, it shows as follows:

```
$ hexo init
INFO  Cloning hexo-starter to E:\Blog
Cloning into 'E:\Blog'...
remote: Counting objects: 65, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 65 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 62
Unpacking objects: 100% (65/65), done.
Submodule 'themes/landscape' (https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-theme- 
landscape.git                                              ) registered for 
path 'themes/landscape'
Cloning into 'E:/Blog/themes/landscape'...
remote: Counting objects: 819, done.
remote: Total 819 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 819
Receiving objects: 100% (819/819), 2.54 MiB | 1.85 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (432/432), done.
Submodule path 'themes/landscape': checked out 
'73a23c51f8487cfcd7c6deec96ccc754                                              
3960d350'
INFO  Install dependencies
▒▒Ϣ: ▒▒▒ṩ▒▒ģʽ▒޷▒▒ҵ▒▒ļ▒▒▒
'npm' ▒▒▒▒▒ڲ▒▒▒▒ⲿ▒▒▒Ҳ▒▒▒ǿ▒▒▒▒еĳ▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ļ▒▒▒
WARN  Failed to install dependencies. Please run 'npm install' manually!
```

So it failed to install a dependency, so I manually add dependency by running `npm install`, and It shows the following issues:

```
> nunjucks@3.1.2 postinstall E:\Blog\node_modules\nunjucks
> node postinstall-build.js src

'node' ▒▒▒▒▒ڲ▒▒▒▒ⲿ▒▒▒Ҳ▒▒▒ǿ▒▒▒▒еĳ▒▒▒
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ļ▒▒▒
npm WARN rollback Rolling back ajv@4.11.8 failed (this is probably 
harmless): EP                                              ERM: operation 
not permitted, lstat 'E:\Blog\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 
(node_modules\fse                                              vents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@                                              1.1.3: wanted 
{"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}                                              
)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nunjucks@3.1.2 postinstall: `node postinstall-build.js src`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nunjucks@3.1.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
log                                              ging output above.
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can try `sudo npm install` or `npm install`

then `hexo g` and `hexo s`

Finish:
INFO  Start processing
INFO  Hexo is running at http://localhost:4000 . Press Ctrl+C to stop.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem today and solved it by using cnpm instead of npm.

```
cd your-dir-need-nunjucks
cnpm install
```